# Ido-mode and similair named files

Tags: emacs

I'm having a problem on my Linux(Mint) box with ido-mode and similar named files. If I have a file name myseq.ml~ and I want to create a file named myseq.ml(myseq.ml doesn't exist) with C-x C-f, I can't find a way to ignore ido-mode's choices. The ido-mode keeps choosing myseq.ml~.

My .emacs file's entry for ido-mode:

```
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(ido-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once ido-mode has suggested a filename that is close to what you want, you can use `C-f` to exit ido-mode and edit the filename normally.